# How to instantiate List only once in runtime(Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, instantiation

I wrote a Page where i can add Objects. Now i also wanna be able to delete Objects. But i always get an error if try to delete an object, after i swapped to another Page (in my Bottomnavigationbar) and back. 
The error: `setState() called after dispose(): _DevicesPageHeroState#09bb8(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)`.

its probably because i instantiate my list again if i reload the `DevicesPageHero`. I thought the `static` might would fix it but looks like it does not.

```dart
class _DevicesPageHeroState extends State<DevicesPageHero> {
  List<String> newMatrixNames = ['Default'];
  static List<Matrix> matrixList = [
    Matrix(
        heroTag: 'm1',
        name: 'Matrix Kitchen',
        matrixIMG: 'imgs/matrix1.png',
        size: 10),
  ];

  static List<Widget> matrixCall = [
    MatrixPageOne(
      matrix: matrixList[0],
    )
  ];
```

The matrixCall list is neccecary to tell what page should be loaded later.
i add a listelement like this:

```dart
  void addMatrix(String name, int size) {
    final Matrix newMat = Matrix(
        name: name,
        matrixIMG: 'imgs/matrix4.png',
        size: size,
        heroTag: DateTime.now().toString());

    setState(() {
      matrixList.add(newMat);
      matrixCall.add(MatrixPageOne(
        matrix: newMat,
        delm: deleteMatrix,
      ));
      print("matrixList");
      print(matrixList);
    });
  }
```

and delete it like this:

```dart
  void deleteMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    setState(() {
      matrixCall.removeAt(matrixList.indexOf(matrix));
      matrixList.remove(matrix);

      print(matrixList.length);
    });
  }
```

If u have any ideas how i could only instantiate my Matrix list the first time i load the `DevicesPageHero` i would be very happy. And sorry if i do some stuff too complicaded just started with coding.

EDIT: Here is the Error produced step by step(sorry for my paint skills):
[image: Error Step by step]
And here the exact error:
[image: Error]

Comment: If it is static matrix (matrix only used to decided next and previous page) better to make it static const field (If necessary create a static function which returns this matrix). This is what I understood from your title and post.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're checking the mounted state before the setState method happens:

```
@override
void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }
```

That snippet will help you up with the error you're having.

Comment: Ah i tried that already, but then nothing Happens If i Press the delete button after i reloaded the Page

Comment: but it its true that it makes the error disappear. But sadly in my case its neccecary to fix the source of the problem

Comment: Do you have a small GIF, screenshots or video of the behavior? to have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish in terms of UI and maybe there's a way around.

Comment: Ah yea shure, comming in a moment

Comment: Ohh some intresting Stuff just happend, ive build the app and put on my phone to run it smoothly ( my emulatur is pritty leggy) and there is nothing going wrong anymore :0

Comment: Ok but tbh im even more irritated now, why is the exact same code working on my phone but not on my emu :0

Comment: Is a difficult thing to know without the emulator settings. Normally (Android) you should use the ones with Play Servicies and yes, those are normally slower than real phones. Plus, if you delete an element you should send an action over the Navigator, pop that page and then delete the object from the list once you're over the behind one.